# Are R snippets simple text templates?

Tags: r, code-snippets, bookdown

something unexpected happened when I used a code snippet in R Studio.
I was editing a .rmd file as part of a bookdown site.

I created the Snippet:

```
snippet tweet
    `r blogdown::shortcode('tweet', 'tweet code')`
```

but when I used that snippet I got:

```
{{% tweet "tweet code" %}}
```

This is actually pretty cool, since it does work as intended and it's a cleaner syntax.
I just want to know what caused this to happen.
I had assumed snippets were a simple copy and paste type operation.

Comment: The confusion occurred because I was expecting the literal output to be pasted into my script (since bookdown wants r code wrapped in backticks to action shortcodes) but because I was expecting snippets to work as simple text replace macros I hadn't considered that bookdown is doing much the same thing (i.e. running r code in text that it's given).

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be:

No, snippets in RStudio are not simply text macros they can also execute R code.

For example the default snippet ts:

```
snippet ts
  `r paste("#", date(), "------------------------------\n")`
```

executes the included paste function to insert a timestamp comment.

Comment: As someone has mentioned in an edit (not a comment) this is apparently a fairly common behaviour across different IDE's. (It's not a part of the r language I don't think?) but other IDE's also execute script in snippets. So, good to know.